# Pycharm shortcut for creating a assignment operator

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, data-science

When using RStudio, you can create assignment operator " > " by pressing Alt + -

In Pycharm, can you use any shortcut key to create the assignment operator like " = "

I was not sure how to create such a shortcut in pycharm's keymap

If I can use such shortcut or create one, that will speed up my development. Any suggestions will greatly help

Answer (score 0):

OK, its pretty simple.
!) I had first to start a macro recorder in pycharm to record my typing of " = " (Edit > Macros > start Macro REcording
2) Save that macro with a name
2) Then assign that macro a shortcut in the keymap settings
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html